# Xcode 11 swift package manager unable resolve packages

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode11

I keep on getting the following error when building a project in Xcode 11 which includes a couple of swift packages added via new Xcode interface

```
Showing All Messages :terminated(1): /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git -C /Users/<xyz>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<xyz>-cqkqfkidemtecxegtugdwffhvvmp/SourcePackages/checkouts/ios-sign-in-with-apple checkout -f 2b61cc97dea9d34f913c22c799476eb8e0a31144 output:
Note: checking out '2b61cc97dea9d34f913c22c799476eb8e0a31144'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 2b61cc9 inicial project

This repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/post-checkout.
```

Comment: As I can see, you are in a detached head. Try to resolve that by creating a new branch and switch to it then try it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linking git-lfs solved the issue

```
ln /usr/local/bin/git-lfs /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git-lfs
```

Got the inspiration from here [github link](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/853)