# Swift package manager does not work with Git LFS

Tags: ios, swift, git, git-lfs, swift-package-manager

I gave private library git repository which has LFS configured. I have converted that library to SwiftSPM compatible by adding Package.swift file. My package is working fine locally when I am adding it to my app project by drag and drop. But if I am trying to add as swift package manager from Xcode I am getting below error

**Couldn’t check out revision ‘cdd1352f7a46a3eb6ea2f087da5fd4e5fcc5254c’:**

**error transferring "f2f56588141b3b3fa7bb8c136079b5b38cf8615441dde51d90aa4fffdc8db342": [0] remote missing object f2f56588141b3b3fa7bb8c136079b5b38cf8615441dde51d90aa4fffdc8db342**

I have gone through couple of links

1. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/676670
2. [Xcode 11 swift package manager unable resolve packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57055604/xcode-11-swift-package-manager-unable-resolve-packages)
3. https://forums.swift.org/t/swiftpm-with-git-lfs/42396/4

But nothing worked for me : Here are my set up details

Xcode 12.5
git-lfs/2.13.3 (GitHub; darwin arm64; go 1.16.2)
git version 2.30.1 (Apple Git-130)

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: This error message is typical for a submodule where the submodule commit has never been pushed to the right place. Are you using submodules?

Comment: @torek , my package git does not have submodule. There is a sample git project available. The problem is there as well. Link:  https://github.com/jml5qh/swiftpm-lfs

Comment: OK - this seems to be a Git-LFS problem. It's definitely not Git itself, and probably unrelated to Swift either.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around this for people who want to use LFS and SPM together, without making their package consumers add steps for installing/linking LFS. Note: this only works if the files you have in LFS are optional, and not needed as part of your package build. In my case we used it for snapshot test PNGs (only needed to run tests, not needed to build/use the package).

Basically you make LFS optional, and only configure it for package developers, but not package consumers.

Steps:

- Remove the lfs config lines from your `.gitattributes` file and check in this removal. Make sure this change makes it into main/master as SPM checks that our first, and will fail with LFS config.
- Move the lines you removed into your `.git/info/attributes` file -- this is local to only you and isn't checked in. This allows you as the package dev to keep using LFS. I made a gitattributes_package_dev_template file with instructions on how to setup LFS locally for other package devs, and checked those instructions in.
- run `swift package purge-cache`  to remove old cache
- Try a fresh package clone in another dir. You should see the files pulled down as pointers  (~150 bytes), not giant binaries. Nice because package install is fast as we are skipping the large files.
- Try installing your package in a fresh Xcode project. It should now work!
- Optional: add `git lfs install && git lfs pull --include="*" --exclude=""` to a script people run when they do local package development. This will install LFS hooks, and convert the pointers into binaries.
- Setup a new release if you already have releases. Prior ones will be stuck with LFS issues.